# how to set asp.net default subdomain to www?

Tags: asp.net

If have a website myws.com, if I request myws.com or www.myws.com I will see the same website

what I want is to be redirected to 'www.myws.com' when requesting 'myws.com'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve a canonical redirect for the www subdomain, if you're using ASP.NET 4.0 you can do this:

```
if (!Request.Url.Host.ToUpper().Contains("WWW"))
{
  Response.RedirectPermanent("http://www.myws.com/" + Request.Url.PathAndQuery, true);
}
```

You can also use the [IIS URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite), once you've installed it add this to your web.config file:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="WWW Canonical Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^myws.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.myws.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got access to IIS, you can use URL rewrite to permanently redirect traffic from myws.com to www.myws.com. Follow this tutorial: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/27/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www.aspx for URL rewrite.

If you don't have access to IIS, then you can add the following code into your global.asax.vb within the Application_BeginRequest event:

```
If Request.Url.Authority.ToString <> "www.myws.com" Then
    Response.RedirectPermanent(Request.Url.Scheme.ToString() & "://www.myws.com" & Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString())
End If
```